# JS: + variable is this right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "misc/AddFriend.php",
    data: {
        mode: 'ajax',
        friend: c,
        uID: $('#uID').val(),
        fID: $('#fID').val(),
        bID: $('#bID').val()
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('OK');
        $('#friend' + fID).slideUp('slow');

    }
});
```

IS this right? It wont slide up right now

Comment: do you get any error message?
tried debugging with firebug?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can find out the ID by alerting the result of the concatenated expression.

Since you're feeding an anon object you don't have a reference. It's probably easiest if you just invoke `.val()` again:

```
    $('#friend' + $('#FID').val() ).slideUp('slow');
```

Otherwise it's probably doing `$('#friendundefined').slideUp`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "misc/AddFriend.php",
    data: {
        mode: 'ajax',
        friend: c,
        uID: $('#uID').val(),
        fID: $('#fID').val(),
        bID: $('#bID').val()
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('OK');
        $('#friend' + $('#fID').val()).slideUp('slow');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct, but whether those ids and the value of variable `c` make sense in the context of your application is a different story.

I notice that you are using `fID` in the function to execute when the call succeeds. `fID` and also `c` would need to be defined outside of the function - I mean that you can't use the value of property `fID` of the object assigned to `data`.

You could create that object outside of the `ajax` function however and use the property for both `data` and in the selector in the function to run when the call succeeds.